How to solve the warning "Component LayoutLoader is missing template or render function" in nuxt3?
I have started a project on nuxt3, and after installation everything works well, except one warning I cannot succeed to clear.
Everytime I load a page, I have this warning on the server console:

WARN  [Vue warn]: Component LayoutLoader is missing template or render function.

Do you have any clue on why it is showing?
I have tried to look into my code, but I have no component named LayoutLoader.
The only occurence of LayoutLoader I find is in the .nuxt folder, but as it is autogenerated I don't know where it comes from.
I have tried to delete .nuxt folder and rebuild, but the error persists
